# cant access router after deleting win server with dimain

Tags: active-directory, vmware-workstation, windows-server-2016, domaincontroller, local-network

I had windows server 2016 AD DC with DNS and DHCP installed on vmware with bridged connection to my home netgear router.
i had deleted the roles of my DC and AD but not the DHCP nor DNS and then deleted the whole vmware machine files off my drive and now i can't access my router.
only if i set every device in my home network with static ip address with gateway 192.168.1.1, i can get internet.

ping results: 
Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.

my server was with static ip address 192.168.1.98.

ping results:
Pinging 192.168.1.100 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.98: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.98: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.1.98: Destination host unreachable.

please help he get to my router.
thank yall.

Answer (score 0):

well, after i found out that i still got the VMWARE hard disk that contain the dns server data (same name to machine and hard disk), i deleted those and rebooted the PC and reset the router to default.
my router pulled the static WAN ip address automatically and i was able to redefine my LAN through my router in my gateway address.